# How do I use 'from /path/module import function' where my /path/module is stored inside of a variable in python?

Tags: python, import, module, operating-system, sys

I am trying to do from /path/module import function, but my path to the module is stored inside of a variable, and I can't change that. How can I work around this then and get this import to work? It is imperative that I import only the function.

I would like something like

```
from path_variable import function
```

where path_variable is the path to my python script that I am extracting the function from.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

Comment: Or, in short: `importlib.import_module(path_variable)`

Comment: There is a function named `import_string` in `werkzeug`.